# How to use regions' names as labels in spatial Data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, spatial

I use the following code to visualize some `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` with ggplot2:

```
require(shapefiles) 
require(sp)

xx <- readShapeSpatial(system.file("shapes/sids.shp", package="maptools")[1],
                   IDvar="FIPSNO", proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=clrk66"))


xx.ff <- fortify(xx,region="NAME")

x <- ggplot(xx.ff) +
aes(long,lat, fill = id) +
geom_polygon()
```

to end up with:

[image]

Assume that I am using `fill` to represent something else, like regional theft rate. Thus I want to label those regions with their names. is there a way to write the regions name right onto the map into the corresponding region, e.g. I want to write Halifax right onto the region.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at similar/related questions I asked:

[ggplot centered names on a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441436/ggplot-centered-names-on-a-map)

[Improve centering county names ggplot & maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441778/improve-centering-county-names-ggplot-maps)

[Plot county names on faceted state map (ggplot2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233623/plot-county-names-on-faceted-state-map-ggplot2)

Comment: +1, thanks a lot, man, really. I was struggling to find the right expression to google it.