# How do I combat "Error in Polygon" error message when trying to find centroid for map labeling?

Tags: r, maps, ggplot2

I'm trying to fill in counties of states with data to help with a project I'm working on. I found a wonderful answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441778/improve-centering-county-names-ggplot-maps/9450588#9450588) on how to add county names to the county map of New York. I was able to use it to help on a few states, but am striking out when I attempt to use the maps of Texas and Louisiana. For reference, this is what I'm typing:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sp)
library(maps)
getLabelPoint <- function(county) {Polygon(county[c('long', 'lat')])@labpt}
df <- map_data('county', 'louisiana')
centroids <- by(df, df$subregion, getLabelPoint)
```

It's at that point R spits out "Error in Polygon(county[c("long", "lat")]) : ring not closed"

I honestly don't even know where to start to fix this, so any help or even an alternative method would be awesome.

Comment: Figure out which polygon is the problem, and add a final point equal to the initial point.  If you've got a GIS specialist nearby they can do it for you, or there's likely some automated method using GRASS or qgis.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman they all look closed to me.... try `DT <- data.table(df); DT[ ,list(Closed=head(long,1)==tail(long,1)&head(lat,1)==tail(lat,1)),by=group]` assuming my data.table logic is correct (no guarantees on that front!)

Comment: +1 for providing a reproducible problem.

Comment: @SimonO101 Nice find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from splitting the dataframe on the wrong variable. You should use `group`, not `subregion` (see end of post), however, rather than `by` how about trying `sapply` instead? I think it gives nicer formatted and more easily useable output:

```
 t( sapply( unique(df$group) , function(x) Polygon(df[df$group==x,c("long","lat")])@labpt ) )
#          [,1]     [,2]
# [1,] -92.40716 30.29909
# [2,] -92.82364 30.65532
# [3,] -90.91371 30.20234
# [4,] -91.06610 29.90319
# [5,] -92.00565 31.08009
# [6,] -93.34896 30.65511
# ..........
```

#### edit

the problem was more simple than I imagined! You were splitting on the wrong group variable, should be `group` NOT `subregion`. However, my solution gives nicer more useable output for placing labels than the funny formatting of `by` (IMHumbleO)

```
centroids <- by(df, df$group, getLabelPoint)
```

Comment: AWESOME, thanks. Splitting by subregion causing the issue makes sense. After I dug through, each of these states has a county (or parish, whatever Louisiana) with two polygons associated. I do like sapply more too, so I'm definitely going to use that.

Comment: @midwestoast happy to help, glad you found it useful! :-)