# How to label countries, not regions, using maps.text in the R maps package

Tags: r, maps, spatial

There don't appear to be any examples in the documentation for the maps package or on stack overflow  of anyone trying to plot text or other information in place of a country name, rather than regions within a country.

```
library(maps)

test <- structure(list(countries = structure(c(3L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("France", 
"Germany", "Italy", "UK"), class = "factor"), value = c(20, 13, 
42, 6)), .Names = c("countries", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")

map.text("world", c("France", "Germany", "Italy", "UK"))
```

[image: Map with all regions labelled, rather than just the country names]

I plan on replacing the country names with the values. The solution might look something like

```
map.text("world",test$countries, labels=test$values)
```

but I can't figure out how to get it to leave out all the unnecessary region labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map.text` tries to match regions with regex, causing the problem. You can either use `exact = TRUE` to disable this, or take advantage of it by putting a `$` (end of line) after each. The UK is not strictly speaking a country, though, so you need to select the component parts, or otherwise work around it.

All told,

```
map.text("world", region = c("France$", "Germany$", "Italy$", 
                            "UK:Great Britain", "UK:Northern Ireland"))
```

returns
[image: plot with 5 names]
which is better, if not exactly perfect. Setting the labels lets us make it look like we want:

```
map.text("world", region = c("France$", "Germany$", "Italy$", 
                             "UK:Great Britain", "UK:Northern Ireland"), 
         labels = c("France", "Germany", '', "UK", "Italy"))
```

[image: plot with four names]
Careful, order in the labels argument is finicky.

If you reconstruct `test` as such:

```
test <- data.frame(countries = c("Germany$", "France$", "UK:Northern Ireland", 
                                 "UK:Great Britain", "Italy$"),
                   value = c(42, 6, '', 13, 20), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

so it looks like

```
> test
            countries value
1            Germany$    42
2             France$     6
3 UK:Northern Ireland      
4    UK:Great Britain    13
5              Italy$    20
```

you can plot the `value` column as the label:

```
map.text("world", region = test$countries, labels = test$value)
```

[image: plot with number labels]

Comment: This definitely works but you're right, there's a serious issue with labels and regions not being applied in the same order. There's [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30305806/4507677) I found that explains how to calculate the centre of a region's polygon for the purposes of graphing in ggplot. Now that I can pull out just the relevant regions I'm sorted. Thanks very much.

Comment: You're right, the `labels` argument is really sensitive to order, and I'm really not sure what order it wants (a bug, I think). If you're doing this for a really big map with hundreds of labels, this approach may be impractical.