# Display values corresponding to the USA states over the state name

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, choropleth, choroplethr

I was trying to create the US states map using the package "choroplethr" and using a simple df2 data set (it has the same region and values column) and I used the code provided in package document.

```
require (choroplethr)

data("df_pop_state")

df2 <- read.csv("ShareDF-chro.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)



# here is the data ShareDF-chro

region = c("alabama", "alaska", "arizona", "arkansas", 
"california", "colorado", "connecticut", "delaware", "district of columbia", 
"florida", "georgia", "hawaii", "idaho", "illinois", "indiana", 
"iowa", "kansas", "kentucky", "louisiana", "maine", "maryland", 
"massachusetts", "michigan", "minnesota", "mississippi", "missouri", 
"montana", "nebraska", "nevada", "new hampshire", "new jersey", 
"new mexico", "new york", "north carolina", "north dakota", "ohio", 
"oklahoma", "oregon", "pennsylvania", "rhode island", "south carolina", 
"south dakota", "tennessee", "texas", "utah", "vermont", "virginia", 
"washington", "west virginia", "wisconsin", "wyoming"), 

value = c(1.15, 0.11, 6.21, 2.41, 8.42, 13.57, 3.57, 4.55, 7.08, 9.42, 5.21, 
0.108, 9.09, 2.56, 4.51, 9.65, 6.76, 3.54, 0.17, 1.99, 6.66, 
3.88, 7.31, 4.86, 4.85, 2.39, 0.25, 0.05, 0.21, 0.11, 3.86, 0.05, 
7.31, 1.91, 0.41, 4.55, 0.002, 2.65, 3.14, 0.71, 1.94, 0.13, 
2.2, 12.65, 0.05, 0.074, 5.79, 7.5, 0.12, 2.6, 0.33)

df_pop_state$value <- df2$value

state_choropleth(df_pop_state,title = "US State's X-Capital share data",num_colors = 2,legend = "Capital Share")
```

[image]

My question is: How can I insert the corresponding X-capital share values inside the map along with the state's acronyms (while like to keep the acronym's font size bit smaller). Thanks and I appreciate your help.

Comment: Please edit your code to share the actual data. You can do this by typing `dput(df_pop_state)` in R and then copying that code. This will allow people to run and modify your actual code, and see the output. If your data cannot be shared, then please modify your code to use public data.

Comment: You've asked three separate questions in this post (insert the corresponding values, control the font size, and the one about Hawaii specifically). This is a *question and answer* site. Note that *question* is singular, not plural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a solution just with `ggplot2`.

- Get the polygon data with `usmap::us_map`. (as you did)
- Left join with your share data (Capitalise Your Region Names First)
- [Create centroids for the text annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9441528/7941188).
- Those centroids and the share are best put into a separate data frame
- Draw polygons with `geom_polygon`
- Draw your labels (State abbreviation and shares) with `geom_text`, using paste.(you can also use `annotate`)
- Pass the data separately to each layer. (Empty ggplot main call)

The advantage is the use of ggplot syntax makes control of color/ fill aesthetic very easy and you can also very easily customise line thickness and size of text.

As for the state abbreviations, I only used the first to letters - this may not be the official abbreviation. There is most certainly some vector out there how to convert this easily.

```r
library(usmap)
library(tidyverse)

us <- usmap::us_map()

region <- str_to_title(region)

share_df <- data.frame(region, share)

us_val <- 
  left_join(us, share_df, by = c("full" ="region")) 
#> Warning: Column `full`/`region` joining character vector and factor, coercing
#> into character vector

us_centroids <- 
  us_val %>%
  group_by(full) %>% 
  summarise(centroid.x = mean(range(x)), 
            centroid.y = mean(range(y)),
            label = unique(toupper(str_sub(full,1,2))),
            share = unique(share))

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = us_val, 
               aes(x,y, group = group, fill = share > 3), 
               color = "black",
               size = .1) +
  geom_text(data = us_centroids, 
            aes(centroid.x, centroid.y, label = paste(label, "\n", share)),
            size = 5/14*8) +
  scale_fill_brewer(name = "State Share", 
                    palette = "Blues", 
                    labels = c(`TRUE`="More than 3",`FALSE`="Less than 3")) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**update**
Having said that with the abbreviation - check out ?datasets::state. It contains those abbreviations (`state.abb`), and state names (`state.name`). It also contains data on the centroids (`state.center`). So, a lot of data already inbuilt :)

**Data**

```
region =  c("alabama", "alaska", "arizona", "arkansas", 
           "california", "colorado", "connecticut", "delaware", "district of columbia", 
           "florida", "georgia", "hawaii", "idaho", "illinois", "indiana", 
           "iowa", "kansas", "kentucky", "louisiana", "maine", "maryland", 
           "massachusetts", "michigan", "minnesota", "mississippi", "missouri", 
           "montana", "nebraska", "nevada", "new hampshire", "new jersey", 
           "new mexico", "new york", "north carolina", "north dakota", "ohio", 
           "oklahoma", "oregon", "pennsylvania", "rhode island", "south carolina", 
           "south dakota", "tennessee", "texas", "utah", "vermont", "virginia", 
           "washington", "west virginia", "wisconsin", "wyoming")

share = c(1.15, 0.11, 6.21, 2.41, 8.42, 13.57, 3.57, 4.55, 7.08, 9.42, 5.21, 
          0.108, 9.09, 2.56, 4.51, 9.65, 6.76, 3.54, 0.17, 1.99, 6.66, 
          3.88, 7.31, 4.86, 4.85, 2.39, 0.25, 0.05, 0.21, 0.11, 3.86, 0.05, 
          7.31, 1.91, 0.41, 4.55, 0.002, 2.65, 3.14, 0.71, 1.94, 0.13, 
          2.2, 12.65, 0.05, 0.074, 5.79, 7.5, 0.12, 2.6, 0.33)
```